# Make canvas scroll horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm building a Floor Map Plan for an Expo using `<canvas>`.

With some research and trial-and-error I managed to make my `<canvas>` scroll horizontally. As shown here [Floor Plan Map - Horizontal Only](https://codepen.io/izwicky/pen/VQOLOY)

But I want my `<canvas>` to scroll/move anywhere the user wants. Example: scroll vertically and horizontally at same time.

I tried adding a `Y` axis but it just scrolls diagonally with some weird mouse interaction. Here's the extract of the lines that manage the scrolling:

```
function drawSettings(){
var dragging = false;
var lastX;
var lastY;
var marginLeft = 0;
var marginTop = 0;

//Scroll settings start
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var evt = e || event;
    dragging = true;
    lastX = evt.clientX;
    lastY = evt.clientY;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var evt = e || event;
    if (dragging) {
        var delta = evt.clientX - lastX;
        lastX = evt.clientX;
        lastY = evt.clientY;
        marginLeft += delta;
        marginTop += delta;
        canvas.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
        canvas.style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    dragging = false;
}, false);
//Scroll settings end
}
```

Here's the result of the example above: [Floor Map Plan - Diagonal Error](https://codepen.io/izwicky/pen/XZwbPP)

How can I solve this?

**EDIT FOR FUTURE REFERENCE:** [Floor Plan Map - FULLY WORKING](https://codepen.io/izwicky/pen/QQepxY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do what you did for horizontal dragging, for vertical dragging too, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var evt = e || event;
    if (dragging) {
        var deltaX = evt.clientX - lastX;
        var deltaY = evt.clientY - lastY;
        lastX = evt.clientX;
        lastY = evt.clientY;
        marginLeft += deltaX;
        marginTop += deltaY;
        canvas.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
        canvas.style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I failed to add the line `var deltaY = evt.clientY - lastY;` Silly me... I blame the penguins for this!